# How can I order a group, based on a summary field of a subgroup

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report which has essentially

- Order

  - OrderDetail 1
  - OrderDetail ..
  - OrderDetail n

These details can have parts and/or labour costs associated with them.

Currently, I group based on `OrderId` and then have the `OrderDetail` information in the details section of the report. This works perfectly.

However, now I need to group the `Orders` based on two criteria `OrderType` and `LabourCost` of the entire Order. I have put together a quick formula to determine order.

```
if(Sum({order.Labour}, {order.OrderId})> 0) then
  if({order.type} = "type1") then 1 else 2
else
  if({order.type} = "type1") then 3 else 4
```

Basically, if it should be sorted based on labour then on type. (the `Sum({order.Labour}, {order.OrderId})` sums the labour grouping based on the orderid)

However when I go to the `Group Expert` and add the group by field to my formula and then preview my report it spins (I cancelled the preview after a minute). If I remove the `Sum` portion of the formula then it takes less than a second.

Is there a way to order this report?

Comment: Is `LaborCost` a property of `Order` (as in your formula) or `OrderDetail`?  Is this also true of `Type`?

Comment: @craig, LabourCost is a field on OrderDetail, however, I have created a view that joins Order and OrderDetail so it's just a table with the OrderId & other Order information repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would approach it:

First, create a `sql-expresssion` field that calculates the labor total for each order:

```
// {%TOTAL_LABOR}
(
SELECT Sum(Labour)
FROM   OrderDetail
WHERE  OrderId=Order.OrderId
)
```

Next, create a `formula` field:

```
// {@OrderGroup}
if({%TOTAL_LABOR}> 0) then
  if({order.type} = "type1") then 1 else 2
else
  if({order.type} = "type1") then 3 else 4
```

Finally, create a new group, based on the `formula` field, ensuring that it groups before the order group.  You can suppress the group's header and footer if desired.

Comment: Even better if you are using a view; you can skip the `sql-expression` and build the summary into the `SELECT` clause as a scalar value.